# VBA Highlight cell if blank in a range of columns and highlight the corresponding header column

Tags: excel, vba

I've searched Google, YouTube, and SO and can't find exactly what I need.

In columns DF - DS, with header in row 2 and data starting in row 3, if a cell in one of those
columns is blank, need to highlight the blank cell and the corresponding header cell.

Example:  If a row in Column DH is blank, highlight the blank and DH2.

The below code works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to get the corresponding header to highlight.

```
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

lastCol = last_col(ws)
lastRow = Last_Row_For_Realsies(ws, lastCol)

Set rng = ws.Range("DF3:DS" & lastRow)

rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)

If rng.Interior.Color <> xlNone Then
```

I can't figure out how to get the corresponding header column to highlight.

Comment: You will need to loop the columns testing for blanks in each column.

Comment: `Intersect(ws.Rows(2), rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)`, I think works.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I tried that and got 1004 runtime error.  Did I enter it in the wrong place?Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

lastCol = last_col(ws)
lastRow = Last_Row_For_Realsies(ws, lastCol)

Set rng = ws.Range("DF3:DS" & lastRow)

rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)

If rng.Interior.Color <> xlNone Then
Intersect(ws.Rows(2), rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

Comment: Get rid of the `If rng.Interior.Color <> xlNone Then` for starters.

Comment: Still received the 1004 runtime error. 
Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

lastCol = last_col(ws)
lastRow = Last_Row_For_Realsies(ws, lastCol)

Set rng = ws.Range("DF3:DS" & lastRow)

rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)


Intersect(ws.Rows(2), rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

Comment: What does `Debug.Print rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Address` return to the Immediate Window?

Comment: Compile Error: Expected: expression

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
Sub YourMainSub()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "DF").End(xlUp).Row

    HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow)
    
End Sub


Sub HiliteBlanksAndHeaders(rng As Range)
    Const CLR As Long = 13158650  'RGB(250, 200, 200)
    Dim rngBlank As Range
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone               'clear any previous hilighting
    With rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)  'exclude headers
        On Error Resume Next                       'in case no blanks cells
        Set rngBlank = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0                            'stop ignoring errors
    End With
    If rngBlank Is Nothing Then Exit Sub           'no blanks

    rngBlank.Interior.Color = CLR
    Intersect(rngBlank.EntireColumn, rng.Rows(1)).Interior.Color = CLR
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Tim,  Received run-time error 1004 at the Intersect line of code.  Also, I don't see where the code is specifying just columns DF:DS.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Swap out `ActiveSheet.Range("B3").CurrentRegion` for your actual range....

Comment: I need to call this into my main macro and used "Call HiliteBlanksAndHeaders(ws)" but since (rng As Range) is in the sub title of HiliteBlanksAndHeaders, I received a Compile Error: Argument not optional.  I am very new to VBA and am not sure how to call this.

Comment: Call like this from your main sub `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow)`

Comment: I need the initial ws because that is how I call the worksheet. I have tried Call HiliteBlanksAndHeaders (ws,(ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow)) and Call HiliteBlanksAndHeaders (ws,ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow) and get compile error: syntax error

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: I have to use ws as Worksheet on all my subs because the main sub calls the worksheet.  When I just use   HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow) to call that sub, I get a compile error:argument not optional

Comment: `I have to use ws as Worksheet on all my subs` - no you don't really - it's fine to pass in a Range instead of a worksheet.

Comment: I have tried and it will not work because of the compile error: argument not optional message.  I just tried it on a separate sub and got the same message.

Comment: Compile error points at which line?

Comment: Where I call the sub in the main macro

Comment: And you call the sub like this `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow)` ?   Assuming you're using the same version of `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders`  I posted

Comment: Yes, I am calling the sub like that

Comment: `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders` only has one parameter of type `Range`, and it only gets called with one argument of type `Range`, so it's unclear how you could get "argument not optional". I've updated my post with a complete (tested and working) example, and screenshot of the result.

Comment: The issue isn't that it only has one parameter of type Range, it's that when I call it into the main sub, I have to use Call HiliteBlanksAndHeaders (ws, <and then what you're telling me to use>).  The error is received on the Call line of the main sub.

Comment: In the HiliteBlanksAndHeaders sub itself, I had to have (ws) after the title so it's like this HiliteBlanksAndHeaders(ws, <and the Range parameter>)

Comment: "I had to have (ws) after the title" no you don't "have to".  There's no purpose served by doing that.

Comment: Yes there is.  I receive the compile error: argument not optional message when I do not.  When I have done what you have showed me, I get the compile error: argument not optional message

Comment: Sorry I don't think there's any more I can offer here.  My code as-posted works fine, but there's something you insist on adding which is breaking it.

Comment: I am "insisting on it" because I get the compile error: argument not optional message when I do what you've shown me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: There's one Range-type parameter defined in `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders` , and the call `HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow)` supplies that Range argument.  Nothing is missing and there's no compiler error in my posted code.

Comment: You stated that earlier and I  have stated that I have to use the (ws) in both the sub title and when I call it to my main sub.  I agree, I do not think there is anymore you can offer here.  Thank you anyway, I appreciate you trying.

Comment: *You stated that earlier* and I have stated that I have to use the (ws) in both the sub title and when I call it to my main sub.  I didn't say that, and you don't need to do that.

Comment: I was referring to your statement "There's one Range-type parameter defined in HiliteBlanksAndHeaders , and the call HiliteBlanksAndHeaders ws.Range("DF2:DS" & lastRow) supplies that Range argument." You stated that earlier after my "Yes, I am calling the sub like that ".  Thank you again for trying to help me; I appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me this could be solved using conditional formatting?

- Create a named range **'Data'** with range **$DF$3:$DS$xx**.
  If the range is dynamic, create a dynamic named range:
- Create a cell where you calculate the last row of Data, name it 'LastRow' (I assume if you can do it in VBA you can also do it on the sheet).
- Create a named range 'Data':

> ```
> =OFFSET(Sheet1!$DF$3,,,LastRow-2,14)
> ```

(Or make the number of colums also dynamic if that is the case)

- Create two conditional formatting rules;

  1. apply it to **$DF:$DS**, with a formula:

  > ```
  > =AND(ROW(DF1)>=MIN(ROW(Data)),ROW(DF1)<=(ROWS(Data)+2),ISBLANK(DF1))
  > ```

  and give it a nice color.

  2. apply it to the headers **$DF$2:$DS$2** (or something more dynamic), with
     formula:

  > =COUNTBLANK(INDEX(Data,0,COLUMN(DF2)-MIN(COLUMNS(Data))+1))>0

  and give it a nice color

Comment: No, it needs to be VBA because it is part of a larger macro.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank()` function and `Range.SpecialCells()` method:

```
Sub HighlighThem()
    With Intersect(Range("DF:DS"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then _
            Union(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks), _
                  Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn, .Rows(1))).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

the code is assuming row 1 of columns DF:DS is empty
but it can be easily changed to handle the case it is not

Comment: Hello,  I received runtime error 91 at   .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone.  I tried commenting that out and received runtime error 1004 on  If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then _

Comment: It seems like "Intersect(Range("DF:DS"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)" isn't getting a Range.
Which is the currently active sheet has no data along columns DF through DS